# Refresh identity token from client from code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, fine-uploader, identityserver3

I am using the fine-uploader with an asp.net mvc backend to upload files directly to an azure blob-storage. The **asp.net-server** works as the azure-signature-endpoint(sas). This is all secured with an **identityserver3** and here comes the problem: The **identity_tokens lifetime** is set to 5 minutes(as default). And I want the SAS endpoint to be only called authorized. So a user can only access its own data. But after I have the upload running for the set 5 minutes, it breaks. Of course, because it is not authorized and it returns the login-page from the identity-server(which the fine-uploader, of course, can't handle).

It would be easy to solve this problem, by either setting the lifetime from the token to something higher(but this is unreliable as the upload could take hours or days), or disable the lifetime(yeah would work. But I guess the lifetime has a reason to exist).

#### So my 2 ideas would be:

1. to just authorize the user once(when he starts the download)
2. or to refresh the token by code every time the signature gets generated.

#### First approach

Can I just set a boolean like user is authorized and if this boolean is set just skip authorization and just return the signature or how could I achieve this

#### Second approach

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the id token for API access, an instead use access token. Access tokens are for resources (APIs), whilst id_tokens are purely for authentication. The id_token is only meant to be used to provide the RP with means of knowing who the user is - hence no need for long time span. It's only there for converting into a user session (cookie/principal).

With access tokens you have several approaches for keeping a valid token at a client; either by fetching new ones using the client credentials flow or by using the refresh token approach.

I believe there are samples of both in the samples repo of IdentityServer.

[Samples repo link](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source)

Comment: Thanks @JohnKorsnes for your answer, with API you mean my Controllers, dont you? But in my understanding I need the identity there because thats the place where I am working with the identity. So my Controllers are part of the RP, which is calling a REST-api to get data from based on the users ID

Comment: You can include the id of the user in accesstokens.

Comment: As a flow I am using the hybrid flow with cookie authentication. So how would I request a new access_token exactly?

Comment: By using the offline_access scope and refresh tokens .

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will try that, once it works I'll accept you

Comment: I recommend reading this article btw. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2016/09/27/using-openid-connect/

Comment: I guess I understand it now. Correct me if I'm wrong.
So the user logs in on the IdentityServer, the IdSrv gives my mvc-application an id-token, an access-token and a refresh token. The id_token gets saved in a cookie and the access token gets sent every time, and if it expires a new one is created by the refresh_token. Am I right? And the access token gets sent to the API with every request.

Comment: You only need to keep hold of the id_token in a cookie if you need it for something like post signout redirect. Otherwise, just disgard it after parsing/validating/setting a cookie w/ user info.

Comment: Yeah, I am keeping it for the post-signout-purposes, and I found out that the mvc-client is refreshing it automatically if the cookie is timing out, which is partially a problem for me (if I make mvc-action calls by ajax). But I guess I will rework it to make calls from Javascript only and rework the identity-flow to the implicit one. But thanks a lot, you kind of opened my eyes